# Storing and managing Messages in ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, instant-messaging

this question might be a tad unspecific, But im building my own IM app for ios, and i was wondering what mechanisms are generally used to store and manage messages. ie the database or files management systems
Eg like in whatapp.

Just the names would be enough i'll do the following research.

Thankyou.

Comment: You have to synchronised your data with robust server.

Comment: I only need the server for pushing the messages, i would like to store them locally?

Answer (score 0):

A messaging app would generally require the data to be relational so here's a couple of names for you to research:

- SQLite
- Core Data

Comment: Thanks, as novice as this sounds, even for the thread of messages, or would it be in a string file or something? Thanks

Comment: You'll want to store the messages in a database of some description rather than a text file.